# How to solve the following system of PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, finite-differences

I've been struggling for a while with the following system of PDEs in the context of an optimal control problem ($u$ and $v$ are *value functions*).

$$\begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{f(x)}{t+1}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} &= \displaystyle a - be^{v-u} \\
\\
 \displaystyle\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + \frac{f(x)}{t+1}\frac{\partial ^2v}{\partial x^2} &= \displaystyle a - be^{u-v} \end{cases}$$

where $u=u(x,t)$, $v=v(x,t)$ and the domain is $x\in[-1,1]$ and $t\in[0,T]$, with $T$ being a positive real number. Furthermore, $a$ and $b$ are positive real constants, and $f(x)$ is a function of $x$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(-1)=f(1)=0$, and it decays smoothly.

The initial conditions are 
$$u(x,T)=\;\,\,\, Dx$$
$$v(x,T)=-Dx$$

where $D$ is a positive real constant, and the boundary conditions are
$$ \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}(1,t) = \frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2}(1,t) = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}(-1,t) = \frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2}(-1,t) = 0$$

I've attempted to solve the equations numerically using a forward finite differences approach, but given the initial conditions, the exponential term in the right hand side (which is the one that couples both equations) becomes very problematic for $D\gg1$. This is because at $t=T$, $e^{v-u}=e^{-2Dx}$, so as $x$ approaches $-1$ that term becomes $e^{2D}$. Also, by exploring the solution to the related system of ODEs:

$$\begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{d u}{d t}  &= \displaystyle a - be^{v-u} \\
\\
 \displaystyle \frac{d v}{d t}  &= \displaystyle a - be^{u-v} \end{cases}$$

with the same initial conditions (considering $x$ now as a parameter), which turns out to be

$$ u,v(x,t) = a(t-T) + \log[\cosh(Dx) \pm \sinh(Dx)e^{2b(t-T)}] $$

I get the intuition that the second derivative with respect to $x$ will blow up with $D$ as well.
At this point I'm pretty lost, help would be most welcome.

Comment: Is the problem well posed? Should I add additional information that would make it more approachable? I tried to avoid unnecessary details to the specific issue that I have.